# WebRTC in C for enbedded devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis

I am using WebRTC using kinesis video streams but am facing the following errors while using
`./kvsWebrtcClientMaster myChannel`
I have here attested the error that i am getting

````
2020-12-04 05:07:58 ERROR   lookForSslCert(): operation returned status code: 0x4000000e
2020-12-04 05:07:58 ERROR   freeSampleConfiguration(): Failed to cancel time queue: 0x00000001
[KVS Master] createSampleConfiguration(): operation returned status code: 0x4000000e 
[KVS Master] Terminated with status code 0x4000000e[KVS Master] Cleaning up....
[KVS Master] Cleanup done```
Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
Thank you.
````

Answer (score 1):

The error code 0x4000000e means STATUS_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_STAT_ERROR as per the following documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-errors.html